# Parse Query fails : unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I try to do a query to find which "Enfants" is provided by a "Lutin". I get the Lutin and i create a query on "Enfant"

```
public class SeeEnfantForLutinActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Lutin lutin;
String lutin_ID;
List<Enfant> list_enfants = new ArrayList<>();

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_see_enfant_for_lutin);

    TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_enfant_lutin);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    lutin = bundle.getParcelable("LUTIN");
    lutin_ID = bundle.getString("LUTIN_ID");
    label.setText(getString(R.string.label_enfant_for_lutin, lutin.getName()));

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_enfant_lutin);

    ParseQuery<Enfant> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Enfant");
    query.whereEqualTo("Lutin",lutin);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Enfant>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Enfant> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for (Enfant en : objects) {
                    list_enfants.add(en);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<Enfant> enfantArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<Enfant>(SeeEnfantForLutinActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_enfants);
                list.setAdapter(enfantArrayAdapter);
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}
}
```

But at the line :
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

There is a Exception thrown :

> com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject

Where the error can be ? I succeed to the same thing with primitive objects ( String, int, ... )

Comment: what are you looking from table..???

Comment: I search the "Enfant" which have the "Lutin" in the variable lutin as "Lutin" . Fields of the "Enfant" table are "name" "city" and "Lutin"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("yourTable");
    query.whereEqualTo("Lutin",lutin);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                      //do your work
            }else{

            }
        }
       });
```